Macbook Air 2017 Thunderbolt to HDMI no signal to external moniter. Monitor detected in displays but no signal-Detects only when I wake up from sleep
I've been using a MacBook Air 2017 model for the past 4 years. I recently bought an external monitor and tried to connect it with a Thunderbolt to HDMI cable, but I don't see any signal on the monitor. If I put the system to sleep / shutdown / restart it with the cable connected, the display gets detected in System Preferences -> Displays. I can see the monitor's name and change the resolution options, but there is still no signal to the external monitor.
Troubleshooting methods I have tried:

Checking the cable with my friend's MacBook Air (same model): It works perfectly.

Detecting displays in System Preferences: When I click the "Detect Displays" button, the system screen turns off for a few seconds, the Apple logo appears with a loading indicator, and then it returns to normal home screen.

I did Reset NVRAM and SMC. And I also erased the OS and installed a new one from recovery mode. These methods did not work for my system.

Unloading and loading the kext files for Thunderbolt: I tried this, but I am unable to unload the kext files and get the following error:
(kernel) Can't remove kext com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily; services failed to terminate - 0xdc008018.
Failed to unload com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily - (libkern/kext) kext is in use or retained (cannot unload).


My system details

Macbook Air 2017
MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

Driver detail
Thunderbolt Bus:

Vendor Name:    Apple Inc.
Device Name:    MacBook Air
UID:    0x000100181A924530
Route String:   0
Firmware Version:   27.2
Domain UUID:    D5B181F9-9087-7C53-AC1C-E58307E86C56
Port:
Link Status:    0x101
Speed:  Up to 20Gb/s x1
Current Link Width:    0x1
Receptacle:    1
Link Controller Firmware Version:  0.15.0

Feel free to share solutions let me try it. Thanks in advance :)

Could you provide the model of the display and cable? Or, at least a link to some website that mentions the display and cable.

@David
Here you can find it
Display link.
Cable - BlueRigger 4K Mini DisplayPort to HDMI 2.0 Cable link

When you tested the cable using your friends a Mac, were you using the same display?

FYI, when you plug the cable into the Mini DP jack on your Mac, the jack operates in DP mode and not in Thunderbolt mode. This means the jack outputs display port signals directly from the GPU. This has nothing to do with the Thunderbolt bus and kext files.

Yes, tested with the same cable and display with friends mac.
Okay, David, I understand. Then what I have to do now to resolve this?

If both Mac are the same and both are running the same version of macOS, then I would assume your Mac has some sort of hardware failure.

There is a difference in OS level my friend laptop has Monterey 12.1, I tried to install the same version but it's not available in the apple server (In sofwareupdate from terminal), so I installed the latest one 12.7.5 after installing I checked same no signal to external monitor and airplay also stopped working. So I go back to Catalina again.
David, is there any way to ensure the hardware failure?

Checked in System report -> Graphics / Displays Monitor is detecting and details showing correctly

I do not know of a way to confirm if there is a hardware failure. Maybe some other user will post a way. Note that the Owner's Manual does state that using a "DP (DisplayPort) to HDMI cable may cause compatibility issues."

There is some "OnScreen Control" software that the manufacturer recommends you install. Enter 29WL500 on this webpage.

Yes it's mentioned "DP (DisplayPort) to HDMI cable may cause compatibility issues."  But it works for my friends mac.
I'm going to download the OnScreen Control and check once.
And one more thing I have noticed If I keep my laptop connected with the monitor after sometime, laptop automatically shut down and displays crashed screen and automatically restarts to back.
